# How to add array to custom inspector?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, unity-game-engine

How would I add a variable to a unity3d custom inspector the documentation is useless and I have tried adding serializable statement above variable and decalring it as an int field in custom inspector as the array is an integer. I am lost if anyone knows what to do on the custom side of things please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at the official tutorials?

Here, [http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/210076/arrays-declaration-c.html](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/building-custom-inspector) you have an example of inspector customizing.